# Binary Search Tree destructor c++

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to make a Binary Search Tree recursively and I had some troubles with the destructor.
My BST is named BSNode based on a class using:

```
private:
    int _count;
    string _data;
    BSNode* _left;
    BSNode* _right;
```

this is my current destructor:

```
BSNode::~BSNode()
{
    if (this == NULL)
        return;
    else if ((this->_left == NULL) && (this->_right == NULL)){
        delete (this);
        return;
    }
    else if (this->_left == NULL)
    {
        this->_right->~BSNode();
        delete (this);
        return;
    }
    else if (this->_right == NULL)
    {
        this->_left->~BSNode();
        delete (this);
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        this->_left->~BSNode();
        this->_right->~BSNode();
        delete (this);
        return;
    }

}
```

I have a problem that after a while (destructing the "nodes" of the class), the program stops and when I started debugging the program , I saw that when the function reaches the end of the tree, it doesn't destory the node and keep getting the same node as if the function was called recursively with the same node.
How can I fix it?

[This is the error I get every time the program enters the destructor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/157z1.png)

Comment: Don't call destructor functions explicitly.

Comment: are you trying to free a single node or the whole tree?

Comment: @pwilmot I'm trying to delete the whole tree starting from the children and then the node itself.
What I mean is start from the bottom until the top - the root.

Comment: the function delete calls an objects destructor so to call delete(this) in the destructor will create a potential infinite loop.

Comment: @pwilmot yes , that's what happend , how  can I fix the function in a way it deletes the current node if it has no sons or something below it without entering an infinite loop then?

Comment: Use smart pointers and you do not have to write any code at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for something more like this

```
BSNode::~BSNode()
{
    delete(_left);
    delete(_right);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @pwilmot , I'll try to test it in my program!

edit: Thank you very much , it does delete the whole tree, once again, Thanks!

Comment: `this == NULL` cannot be true in valid code. Also, `delete NULL` is perfectly OK, so `if`s are redundant. The whole body can be compressed to just `{ delete left; delete right; }`.

Comment: @n.m ok , thank you for the information , I wasn't sure about it before but now I know for sure!

Comment: `this` cannot be null.. save the keyboard as the `this->` is not required. Also delete null is fine. So those if statements are not required.

Answer (score 0):

```
        ~tree()
{
    remove(root);
}
void remove(node* temp)
{
    if (temp == NULL)
        return;
    remove(temp->left);
    remove(temp->right);
    delete temp;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: I guess "delete temp;" will cause infinite loop.